# Tilt a loop cut without affecting the whole form

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, loop

I want to rotate a loop cut from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

If I simply rotate it, it would affect the whole form:

[image]

which isn't what I want.

I know in this particular case, I could've use a knife tool to cut through the cube. But I'd like to know if it's possible to "tilt" an existing loop cut without changing the bounding geometry?

Comment: you can slide the vertex or vertices with GG, you can also select the whole loop and use the Shear tool, but it will only work fine if your object is aligned with the axis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to amplify on @moonboots' comment, you can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> *Shear* tool, (with <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to determine the direction of shear,) which works in View space.

If your cube is not aligned to one of the preset orthogonal views, you can align your view to a face of the cube by selecting the face, and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> on the numpad.

Comment: But this only works for simple case like a cube right? On a twisted form (like a vase) sheer will change the bounding form still.

Comment: The shear will translate straight along the locked dimension, in proportion to the (signed) distance from the pivot, so yes. Perhaps you want to K (+Z) cut through your vase?